# Group Theory: how to find subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to address my weak points with group theory, and thought I could learn this through an example:

> Let $G = (\mathbb{Z}_4 \times\mathbb{Z}_6, +)$.  Find $3$ subgroups of $G$ of size $12$.

The solution:

$$\begin{align*}
H_1 &= \{(2a, b) : a \in \mathbb{Z}_4, b \in \mathbb{Z}_6\} \\
H_2 &= \{(a, 2b) : a \in \mathbb{Z}_4, b \in \mathbb{Z}_6\} \\
H_3 &= \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6 : x + y \text{ even}\}
\end{align*}$$

What is the best way to come to this solution?

Answer (score 1):

The first two are relatively easy:

1. you pick a subgroup of order $2$ of the first factor, times the whole second factor of order $6$;
2. you pick the whole first factor of order $4$, times a subgroup of order $3$ of the second one.

The third one is slightly trickier, as you want to take some *diagonal* elements. Perhaps the simplest way to see it is to take the element $(1, 1)$, and verify that has order the least common multiple of $4$ and $6$, that is, $12$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose any element of order $12$ and generate a subgroup by that element.For example consider $H_1=<(1,2)>$ etc.